# Import data from a test file to the mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, file

I know there are already existing answered questions to my question, but so far, I haven't found one that answers my question 100%.

Anyway, is there a way to [insert title here] wherein the [delimiter] is the number of characters? What I'm trying to say is...example, the text file has three data: name, age and gender. The format would look like this...

> Joseph____18_M (pretend the underscores are spaces)

In the example above, the name has 10 characters, the age has 3 and the gender only has one.

Is there a method in sql to take the first 10 characters in the file, put it on the database, then the next 3 characters, and so on...?

Thanks.

Comment: Just use the [`SUBSTR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) function.

Comment: I think he wants `LOAD DATA` if the goal be to load a flat file into his table.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yeah, like what TimBiegeleisen said, it needs to be `LOAD DATA` since it's a file to database.

Comment: So use `LOAD DATA` and get the separate values out using `SUBSTR()`.

Comment: ...Oh hey, `SUBSTR()` really works. Thanks, @RobbyCornelissen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use mysql's [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) command without specifying a field delimiter or fields optionally enclosed by parameter - but make sure that the file is not a unicode one:

> If the FIELDS TERMINATED BY and FIELDS ENCLOSED BY values are both
>   empty (''), a fixed-row (nondelimited) format is used. With fixed-row
>   format, no delimiters are used between fields (but you can still have
>   a line terminator). Instead, column values are read and written using
>   a field width wide enough to hold all values in the field. For
>   TINYINT, SMALLINT, MEDIUMINT, INT, and BIGINT, the field widths are 4,
>   6, 8, 11, and 20, respectively, no matter what the declared display
>   width is.
>
> LINES TERMINATED BY is still used to separate lines. If a line does
>   not contain all fields, the rest of the columns are set to their
>   default values. If you do not have a line terminator, you should set
>   this to ''. In this case, the text file must contain all fields for
>   each row.
>
> Fixed-row format also affects handling of NULL values, as described
>   later.
>
> **Note Fixed-size format does not work if you are using a multibyte
>   character set.**

Declare the name as varchar(10), age probably as varchar(3) or you may try unsigned tinyint, gender as char(1).